# How to build a dynamic app

Tags: iphone, android

I'm new to programming but have managed to build a rather complex dynamic site using PHP, MySQL, JavaScript and AJAX.

Now I would like to build an app with the same functionality that will use the same database but I have no idea where to start. If it's possible I don't want to learn any more programming languages. Somehow I would like to use parts the code I have already written for the site to run the app and update the database. Are there any softwares that offers drag and drop app building together with PHP? Best is of course if it's possible to build for both Iphone and Android at the same time.

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Are you satisfied with how your site looks in iPhone/iPad/Android browsers? If so, you don't have to learn new prog. languages and can advertise your app as a website. Or maybe making a simple application just with webview opening your site makes sense?

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. Both webview and Phonegap sounds like possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you should look into using phonegap. It creates an app with a webView in which you 'create an app' with HTML / Javascript. From what I saw you can use php in there too, another option is to have the php run on your webserver as RESTful services that you call from you app

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to leverage hardware features, you won't get around writing a native app.

But for your case you could use either [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) or [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/). Those frameworks utilize HTML5 and JavaScript to make mobile `WebApps`.

Comment: Phonegap allows for using some hardware features. http://www.phonegap.com/about/features

Answer (score 0):

well unfortunately if you want to create a dedicated application you will need to learn another language.

Iphones use Objective C and Androids use Java.

that being said you can always make your website different for a hand held phone.
something like this would be handy: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

if you were to go the application route, you wouldn't be able to use the same php code, although you could use the same database, but it would not be a simple process, moving from php to something like java can be a bit tedious as it is hard typed and languages like javascript and php are not. BUT java isn't so bad!

edit:
hmm phone gap sounds interesting! good to know!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there's a way to build iPhone apps without knowing any Objective-C...
You could maybe write the model code in C but there's no way to create the UI without ObjC.

Probably, the only option you have is using a single UIWebView and powering your app using PHP and HTML.